# In Appcelerator / Titaium is it possible to share images across iOS and Android?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I created an app with Appcelerator Studio / Titanium, originally just for iOS and I placed all of my images into the assets folder directly; `app/assets`. All of the images load fine on iOS, for example:

```
<ImageView id="logo" image="logoHorizontalWhite.png" />
```

However, when I build the app for Android, the image doesn't show.

Does this mean I have to place images into the Android specific directory and I will need to have duplicates of all images for both iOS and Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The folder `app/assets` is the "root" folder for images. Recommended is putting all images in `app/assets/images`.

Android is particular about the leading slash. Try:

```
<ImageView id="logo" image="/logoHorizontalWhite.png" />
```

Any images not to be shared across platforms should go to platform specific folders, `app/assets/iphone/images` and `app/assets/android/images`

Comment: Additionally, it is best practice to place images in `app/assets/images`. These images will be optimised during build. Also look at https://speakerdeck.com/fokkezb/getting-started-with-titanium-and-alloy#44 for a best practice on how to organise images for different platform and densities.

Comment: Thanks for comment @FokkeZandbergen. I updated the answer with more info so it won't get lost if your speakerdeck is